# JSP drop down list to select first option by default on page load using struts

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts

Hope someone can help me out on this.

I've got the following drop down list in JSP:

```
<html:select styleId="facilityId" property="facilityId">
<html:options collection="<%=Session.CONSUMER_FACILITY%>"
property="id" labelProperty="facilityDescription"
/> 
</html:select>
```

That gets a collection of list to be displayed in the drop down from the Java class perfectly.

But now when I open the page where it shows the drop down list, how can I make the first option selected by default on page load, without clicking and selecting a option?

Can I do something inside that JSP code or some Javascript that can do that?

I'm using Struts.

Hope this makes sense what i'm looking for.

Comment: are you using struts ?

Comment: yes i am using struts

Answer (score 1):

Set `facilityId` value to expected default during `ActionForm` initialization.

*Guess you're using Struts 1.x*

Comment: @user2319262, you're welcome. Please, post your answer to help future visitors which met same problem.